# CSS Transition not working when input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I read every thread and tried every possible solution and don't know what I missing!

I have a div `video_container_dc` that I would like to fade in when I call it in Javascript.

The CSS:

```css
#video_container_dc {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 198px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 376px;
    opacity: 0;
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
    /*display:none;*/
}
#video_container_dc.expandingVid {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-out 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-out 1s;
    transition: all 2s ease-out 1s;
    opacity:1;
    /*visibility:visible;*/
    /*display:block;*/
}
```

The JAVASCRIPT:

```
var expand_content;
var vidContainer;
var expandTweens = [];

function expand_transition() {
    expandTweens = [];
    expand_content.className = 'expanding';
    vidContainer.className = 'expandingVid';
}

inits = function () {
    expand_content = document.getElementById('expand_content_dc');
    vidContainer = document.getElementById('video_container_dc');
}
```

I tried all this for the tween function to no avail:

```
//vidContainer = document.getElementById('video_container_dc');
//document.getElementById( 'video_container_dc' ).className += 'expandingVid';
//vidContainer.className += "expandingVid"; 
//vidContainer.css("opacity", 0);
//vidContainer.offset();
//vidContainer.css("transition", "opacity 1000ms ease-out").css("opacity", 1);
```

The HTML:
First I run the `inits();` in the html then:

```
<div id="video_container_dc">
    <video id="video_dc" >
        <source id="video_1_mp4_src_dc" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the class being applied correctly? Does it show up in the page?

Comment: If you comment out the properties then they won't be applied, is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: inits should be called after the html.Since the elements are not known until parsed.
call inits at the end of the html.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's possible that the DOM elements do not exist on the page at the time you're calling `expand_transition`. You should make sure your script waits to run until the page is loaded, potentially using something like:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // your code here
}, false);
```

If you're already doing this, if the `expand_transition` function runs immediately on page load, then the browser is probably coalescing your DOM changes. This is a feature provided by most browsers so that you can make a number of changes at once, and they all appear on the page in a single repaint.

Instead of calling `expand_transition` directly, consider trying something like this instead (from your `onload` handler):

```
setTimeout(expand_transition, 0);
```

The artificial delay will be enough to convince the browser that you want it to apply any layout changes before executing your transition function.